# Where can I get information on running the Android apps demo in the WIllow Garage blog video?

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the Willow Garage Blog, I notice the entry: "Creating and running apps on your robot using Android" which shows a tablet interface.  I would like to learn more about it so I can control a robot I'm building by a similar wireless interface, beefed up for more degrees of freedom.

I need some details to reproduce the blog entry.  For hardware, what is the tablet shown?  Also, how do you connect between the tablet and robot?  What wireless receiver on the robot will communicate with the tablet?  Finally, on the ROS site, there is tons of software.  What specifically was used in the blog entry?

Thanks,
Kirk Fraser

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12462/where-can-i-get-information-on-running-the-android-apps-demo-in-the-willow-garage-blog-video?/) by [Kirk Fraser](https://answers.ros.org/users/1574/kirk-fraser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please visit the URL shown in the video:

http://ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform

The app only works with PR2 and TurtleBot so far.  We've only tested on proper the Xoom and Galaxy Tab 10.1. The wireless is standard 802.11 that the tablets support.

The recent Android SDK update has broken the installation instructions, so you'll have to do your own build and deployment to the tablet.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0